# Treatment control graph in R

Tags: r

How would I create a treatment/control graph like in R, assuming I have two vectors of data

`treatment <- c(1,2,3,3,5,6,7)`

`control <- c(4,5,6,6,8,9,10)`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you use the lattice package, you should use something like

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(data~which, make.groups(treatment, control), groups=which)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe add `jitter()` to resolve overplotting?  Like `xyplot(jitter(data)~which, make.groups(treatment, control), groups=which)`